# Comparison shorted dated tbills and determine which asset class is best return

Tags: cross-currency-basis, sofr

i was wondering how to create a comparison table across various time horizons for given currencies and see the return/spread over SOFR.
Any Bloomberg links/functions i could use?
Ideally i would like to create a set of short dated intruments, too, which would show me in this table the pick up vs. SOFR